# Quando usar Em ou %?

Tags: css, layout-responsivo, porcentagem

Estou estudando layout responsivo e já sei que para criar uma parte flexível é necessário usar medida relativa como Em e %. Mas ainda não consegui entender qual a diferença real entre um e outro...

...e se é possível chegar ao mesmo resultado usando apenas % e não ter problemas.

Answer (score 3):

As unidades `em` e `ex` são relativas ao tamanho da fonte. `ex` é a altura do "x" minúsculo, e `em` é simplesmente o "tamanho da fonte" (o nome da unidade vem historicamente de 'a largura do "M" maiúsculo', mas [essa definição não é usada no CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29#CSS)).

[image: Exemplo de ex]

Dessa forma, se você possui um elemento que precisa ser proporcional a um corpo de texto (digamos, uma caixa com texto dentro, de modo que o texto nunca saia da caixa quando a fonte aumenta ou sobre espaço quando a fonte diminui) então o `em` - ou mais raramente o `ex` - é indicado.

Já o `%` é proporcional às dimensões do elemento pai, de modo que se o que você quer é por exemplo que um elemento ocupe 80% do espaço disponível, e outro os 20% restantes, essa unidade é indicada. Há ainda as unidades `vw`, `vh`, `vmin` e `vmax` que são proporcionais à tela inteira (independentemente da hierarquia de elementos), e que [também podem ser usadas para especificar o tamanho da fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35450/215) (não se pode definir o `font-size` em `%`).

Answer (score 1):

[Aqui](http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/css/css_font-size_px_em_pt_ou_keyword) explica a diferença entre todas as métricas do CSS.

**EM**

Unidades de valores EM são as mais complicadas de se trabalhar. Ela é abstrata e arbitária. Aqui tem um exemplo, `1em` é igual ao tamanho atual da fonte do elemento em questão, ou seja, se você ainda não definiu tamanho de fonte em lugar algum na página, então ele vai automaticamente pegar o tamanho de fonte padrão do browser, que provavelmente é `16px`. Então, define-se que por padrão `1em = 16px`. Digamos que você defina na tag `body { font-size:20px }` então o `1em` passará a ser `20px`. Assim que ele funciona.

Outro exemplo: Se você criar uma tag `h1 { font-size: 2em; }`, o tamanho do H1 em `px` vai ser `32px` caso você não tenha definido algum valor ainda no css.

**Porcentagem %**

Porcentagem assim como o nome diz trabalha com percentual de valor. Se um pai tiver o tamanho de `20px`, e você definir o filho com `font-size:50%` ele terá o tamanho de `10px`.

O porcentual é muito bom para trabalhar com as ferramentas de crescer e decrescer o tamanho na página do texto.

Comment: Sendo assim quando é vantajoso usar em? E da pra usar % no layout inteiro e obter resultado satisfatório?

Comment: Não é questão de ser vantajoso. Você deve escolher a metrica que melhor adeque a sua estrutura de layout. Dá sim para usar `%` e ter um resultado legal, isso depende de quem irá montar a página.